# Issue adding to a List of a custom class type

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

This is most probably a very basic issue for someone but I cannot get my head around it. Basically I have a custom class for a List:

```
public class CorrectiveMaintResults
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Cleared { get; set; }
}
```

I eventually store this in a DB which I place a newline delimiter in between each item for both comment and cleared. I then retrieve this to put back into a table. To achieve this I have created two private lists which take the comment and cleared data from the db.

What I am trying to do is create a for or foreach loop to add both the private lists back onto my custom list (correctiveMainResults). THis is what I am trying:

```
for (int i = 0; i < correctiveMainComment.Count; i++)
{
    maintResults.Comment = correctiveMainComment[i];
    maintResults.Cleared = correctiveMainCleared[i];

    FormResults.correctiveMainResults.Add(maintResults);
}
```

mainResults is my initialization of the class:

```
CorrectiveMaintResults maintResults = new CorrectiveMaintResults();
```

The issue I am having is that when the results are added to the the FormResults.correctiveMainResults, it only seems to the last index of each list and just duplicates it.

Hopefully someone can help or understands what I mean. Hard to explain without actually seeing the application running.

Comment: You should be creating a new `CorrectiveMaintResults` in your loop instead of overriding the same object's properties.  Just move the initialization line inside the loop.

Comment: Similar to @linuxrocks. Thanks for the help

Comment: Explanation: What your for loop does is, adding the same object reference multiple times to the list. Which means that every entry of your list just points to the same object. Which after your last loop holds the value of the last index of your helper lists (therefore the duplicates).

Comment: @croxy Ok thanks for the explanation. Appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating only one object outside of your loop. Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < correctiveMainComment.Count; i++) {
    CorrectiveMaintResults maintResults = new CorrectiveMaintResults();
    maintResults.Comment = correctiveMainComment[i];
    maintResults.Cleared = correctiveMainCleared[i];

    FormResults.correctiveMainResults.Add(maintResults);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great! Will accept the answer once it lets me